# Logitech MX518 Custom Clicker?

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

I got an old Logitech MX518 gaming mouse, that, despite its age (2009) still works like a charm. However, recently I decided to take it apart to clean it, but somehow lost the small metallic clicker that's needed for the mouse wheel to stay in place.

[image]

Now the problem is that the wheel is *extremely* loose. I can move itby literally just blowing against its side. That makes it annoying when gaming, as I uncontrollably switch items all the time.

Due to the mouse being discontinued from production, I couldn't find any replacement parts the likes online. Not even the upgraded G400 or G400s seem to offer any.

So the question:
**Does anyone have an idea how to get such a metal piece to make my clicker work again?** (And please don't say I should buy the aforementioned G400 mice, as I will not spend 60 bucks just because I lost a tiny metal thingy.)

Comment: Which piece is actually missing? If you took the photos then you have all the pieces?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that these aren't my pictures, but random ones I found on the internet. I was referring to that bent, metallic thingy you can see well in the bottom left picture.

Comment: The grey wire? You should be able to find the right thickness of wire and bend it ... especially as you have the photos to guide you.

Comment: @DavidPostill - if you can cold bend a piece of wire, it is unlikely to have the necessary springiness to function as intended. Spring steel can't be cold-bent, it must be heated. Also, that particular component is finer than even a tiny paper-clip & is going to be murder to copy, especially without an original to refer to (I have one - I dropped it… I found it again, phew;) I'd be tempted to try use a small blob of something like [Sugru](https://sugru.com) which is very malleable until dry, then rubbery. Clean the grease off properly first, or it won't stick.

Comment: I'd say that your best option is to look for a similar mouse that is broken for some other reason and try the piece out of it. That piece (or something very similar that just might work) is in most Logitech mice. Also look to see if the whole wheel component (bot left pic) could fit in your mouse as well. Hopefully, now you know why it is important to keep your work area clean and organized when disassembling something.

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidPostill states, *cold bending* spring steel is tricky, but it is not impossible, especially for finer sizes. Get steel "[music wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_wire)" of the correct diameter at a hobby shop (where you could bring the mouse innards to check diameter) or [online](http://www.shoppscr.com/piano-wire-tube-and-brass). Try to bend it cold, but if it snaps when bent sharply, try this procedure:

1. Heat the wire to a barely-visible red heat and let it cool it gradually. This will anneal (soften) it. Use a propane torch, alcohol lamp, or pass a few amps through it with a current-regulated power supply, if you have one.
2. Bend it as needed.
3. Heat and quench *immediately* in water or oil to harden it again.
4. It may be necessary to reheat it gently to anneal it, if the wire has become too brittle to reinstall.

It's a bit of work, but not too hard, if the mouse is worth it. See [RC modeling forums](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1573595) for more on bending piano wire.